# Correct Putty configuration for Ubuntu 9.04

Tags: ubuntu, putty

I often use Putty (www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/) to connect to Ubuntu boxes (9.04 now). It works well, but I can't figure out the correct combination of Putty font, character encoding, character translation, and terminal configuration on the Ubuntu end so that the terminal displays everything correctly. The problem is most obvious when running an ncurses program such as "screen-profiles" or "w3m". The box drawing characters are messed up.

Has anyone got this combination working to their satisfaction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try going to PuTTY's "Translation" settings and setting the code page to "UTF-8". Then relogin or redraw your screen (^L). That should do it.

Comment: +1 Never noticed this problem in w3m before, but sure enough there it was in Putty, and this fixed it.

Comment: I freakin love you... I've been wresting with this for days. Didn't think to look there. 2 years later... thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've been using Putty to ssh to both Xubuntu and Ubuntu boxes, and usually the settings have been fine as default - I'm using Putty Tray 0.60 (r3), which is a portable variant.

I'm not using the same translation character settings as Josh K, but everything still works fine for me.